# Fitting a function only within a certain range in python

Tags: python, scipy, range

I'm trying to make a fit of blackbody radiation with some data but I only want to fit with temperatures in the range 4600-6600. I'm not sure how I can put this in this function `popt, pcov = curve_fit(planck,wavelength,flux)`

planck is the function that gives the radiation and wavelength and flux are the data I have.

Comment: Please provide more information and detail.

Comment: No, I want to see which temperature in the range 4600-6600 fits the flux best. I enter the wavelength and temperature in the function planck and it returns a flux I want to know which temperature fits the given flux data best.

Comment: You might want to include your comment inside the post, to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what your function or data actually look like, but as a general rule your function can include logical statements to deal with this sort of situation. For instance:

```
def f(x):
  if 4600 < x <6600:
    return do_something(x)
  else:
    return x
```

Note that this sort of function may or may not be the most elegant way to solve your general problem; it might be wise to set up your code in such a way that inappropriate values don't get passed to the function in the first place.

Does that answer your question?